# Java shift operator

Tags: java, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

Consider the following Java code:

```
byte a = -64; 
System.out.println(a << 1);
```

The output of this code is `-128`

I tried as follows to figure out why this is the output:

64 = 0 1000000 (the MSB is the sign bit)

-64= 1 1000000 (Tow's complement format)

Expected output after shifting:
1 0000000 (This is equal to 0, because the MSB is just a sign bit)

Please anyone explain what I am missing.

Answer (score 3):

The two's complement representation of -128 is 10000000, thus your results are correct.

Answer (score 2):

```
10000000 is -128
10000001 is -127
10000010 is -126
...
```

So `10000000` is not `0`. It is `-128` which was your output.

Comment: Is there any direct arithmetic way to convert two's complement to decimal?

Comment: Do you mean `int i = Integer.parseInt("10000000", 2);`?

Answer (score 2):

This program

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(-64));
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(-64 << 1));
System.out.println("-64 << 1 = " + (-64 << 1));
```

prints

```
11111111111111111111111111000000
11111111111111111111111110000000
-64 << 1 = -128
```

You can see that -64 << 1 is the same as -64 except all the bits have been shift left by 1 (the lowest bit becomes a 0)

Comment: If you want to express `-128` why would you want to write it in this strange way?

Comment: @Imray You might need to write `x << 1` and you might need to know that x=-64 will result in -128.  I can't think of a good reason to write `-64 << 1` except if you want to know what you would get.

Answer (score 1):

In shift operators sign bit is ignored. So 1 1000000 << 1 is 10000000 which is -128.what's the problem?
Our machines are using [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) to represent numbers (signed and unsigned). For representing a negative number machine negates it's positive and adds 1.
-128 is !10000000 + 1 = 01111111 + 1 = 10000000
**EDIT:**
I was wrong, only right shift operator's ignoring the sign bit. 10100000 << 1 == 01000000
For unsigned right shifting there's an operator >>> which shifts sign bit too.
11000000>>1 == 10100000 and 11000000>>>1 == 01100000

Comment: If sign bit is ignored how the result be a signed (negative) number?!

Comment: I don't think "ignored" is quite the right word, but the point is that `10000000 == -128`, not `0` as you thought.

Answer (score 1):

In two's complement, the MSB is not just a sign bit, you're thinking ones'-complement maybe? In 8 bit two complement,

> 10000000 = 0x80 = -128

Comment: Please explain more about the conversion 10000000 = 0x80 = -128 (I don't understand that 0x80) :)

Comment: @MISS_DUKE Read about [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Answer (score 0):

> `<<` means multiply by 2
>
> `>>` means divide by 2

And, during shift operations don't consider signed bit.

Comment: But the machine seems considering the sign bit, because it is presenting a signed number as output?!

Answer (score 0):

I’m wondering. `<< 1` (ignoring all details) is “multiply with 2.” -64 * 2 = -128. So why are you wondering that it indeed is -128?