# What is this expression in Java ( 1 << 2)?

Tags: java, expression

I don't know what this means "1 << 2" in :

```
public static final int MODIFY_METADATA = 1 << 2; // modify object
```

Please help me!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bit_shifts

Comment: Similar questions have been asked and answered on SO, for example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9207007/960195).

Answer (score 6):

If you want to know why would use use `1 << 2` rather than 4 which is the same value, it because you explicitly want to be using a bit mask e.g.

```
public static final int FLAG0 = 1 << 0;
public static final int FLAG1 = 1 << 1;
public static final int MODIFY_METADATA = 1 << 2;
```

Shows each value is in a bit mask.

Answer (score 5):

[Java Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

[Bitwise Operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation)

`<<` is the left bit shift operator.

Comment: SO in your example, this is 1 bit shifted 2 to the left, which evalulates to 4

Comment: @ChrisWhite `1 << 2 = 4`, yes.