# Javascript operators << and >>

Tags: javascript, operators, bit-shift

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do these operators do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535328/what-do-these-operators-do)
>   [What is this expression in Java ( 1 << 2)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9833050/what-is-this-expression-in-java-1-2)

What does >> and << operators in JavaScript do?

I've never seen them before and im breaking my head trying to understand them.

Any help is appreciated :D

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference%2FOperators%2FBitwise_Operators

Comment: trying to find the javascript question that this is a dupe of, if only it wasn't so hard to search for on [SO]

Comment: To address this sort of question about a language, please consult a reference. The keyword is, of course, **operators**. -1 because you knew *what* look for.

Comment: Don't forget `>>>`, `-->`, `-->>`, `-->>>`, `<--` and `<<--`.

Answer (score 0):

They are bit shifting operators.

[Mozilla Reference 1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference%2FOperators%2FBitwise_Operators)

[Mozilla Reference 2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference%2FOperators%2FBitwise_Operators)

Answer (score 0):

They are [bitwise shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift) operators.

In practice they are used to shift bits of variables by the specified amount, eg

```
2 << 2 = 8
```

Answer (score 0):

They are standard bitwise shift operators. You need to draw 1 and 0s on paper to understand it better:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators